# Good losses curves but bad predictions

Tags: neural-network, keras, loss-function

I trained an `LSTM` with a `Dense` layer that has `ReLU` as an activation function.
Training and validation loss decreases in a very good way, however predictions on the test set are bad.

My goal is to predict words order in sentences. It’s a regression task because, for N words, I want N real numbers as output that will be ranked in order to obtain integer numbers representing words position in the sentence

**Example**:

input: "if Google into What ? morphed GoogleOS"

output: "What if Google morphed into GoogleOS?"

Losses:
[image: Losses]

I notice that in the predictions, there are a lot of zeros.

Model architecture:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(timesteps, features)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=200, return_sequences=True, 
                             kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), 
                             recurrent_regularizer=l2(0.01), 
                             bias_regularizer=l2(0.01)), 
                        input_shape=(timesteps, features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
```

Did `ReLU` (negative output is transformed in zero) causes the problem?

Is it a good choice the `linear` activation function in this case?

Comment: Can you just add your model's code? Make sure not to have ReLU just before the output layer.

Comment: @Aditya posted :D

Comment: If you will have -ve logits, then ReLU will squash them to 0, right? You definitely don't want that, do you?

Comment: @Aditya Yes, that’s relu behavior. So I suspect that zeros in the predictions were negative values squashed at zero by relu.

Comment: That's why, you never have activation layer after your logits or the final dense layer! That's the reason it fails. NB, I would strongly suggest, just take a look at some code blocks as to how people structure their nets :)

Comment: @Aditya what do you suggest? Remove activation layer?

Comment: You should not be using linear activation (except in few cases), we want to add non linearity. Think for a sec, if you have two dense layers back to back stacked via the Linear Activation (cx)(the grad is a constant value.), then you can simply replace them with one dense layer. Try sigmoid if you only want 1 neuron as your output. PS I am not sure what's the end goal; list of activation funcs https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115258/comprehensive-list-of-activation-functions-in-neural-networks-with-pros-cons

Comment: @Aditya my goal is to predict words order in sentences. It’s a regression task because, for N words, I want N real numbers as output that will be ranked in order to obtain integer numbers representing words position in the sentence.

Comment: Interesting problem, I have personally never done this but a quick gseaerh points to this https://github.com/BadrulAlom/Sentence-Order-Prediction/blob/master/SentenceOrder/WordOrder.ipynb

Comment: @Aditya this task's goal is to order sentences but words in the sentences are already ordered. My task is different: predict the correct words order in a sentence, given a syntactically unordered sentence.

Comment: @Aditya however, with an MLP with only 1 hidden layer I achieved the task.

Comment: Great, Just curious if you can share an end to end minimal example? Thanks

Comment: @Aditya posted! Another thing: if I had syntactically ordered sentences as input, LSTM would learn to recognize elements in that order, already ordered then.
For this reason, the words of the training set and test set sentences were ordered according to the same criteria (in alphabetical order of syntactic dependencies), so that the model would learn to understand this order.

Comment: @Aditya Ok, now I trained the neural network with ELU (similar to ReLU but admits negative outputs), but predictions still not very good. The losses curves are like the posted one. Do you have any suggestions about this behavior? I'm going out of head.

Comment: Well the problem you are trying to solve is definitely not easy and straightforward, so it will use your brain at max